# How to get the list of objects which are deep archive in the specific bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have lots of objects approximately about 500,000,000 in the bucket.

Since I applied the s3 intelligent tiering, some of the objects are glacier deep archive class.

Under the such scenario, I would like to get the objects which is only going to deep archive class.

To achieve this issue, I wrote the below code using `boto3` in python.

```
bucket = "my-bucket"
response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket)
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix="my-prefix")

for page in pages:
    for obj in response['Contents']:
        # print(obj['Key'])
        if obj['Size'] == 0:
            print(obj['Key'])
```

But it took a lot of times because there are more than 100,000,000 objects in the bucket.
Even though I specified the prefix, it took lots of time.

Is there any faster way to get the object whose class is deep archive?
I think that the procedure iterating all the objects in for loop is quite slow for case where lots of objects is stored in bucket.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You should use S3 Inventory instead of manually listing the objects.